# Calculate Columns to Print Without Scaling

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I would like to calculate whether columns A:G in my spreadsheet will print on an A4 page in portrait mode without scaling.

I know that the width of an A4 page is 210mm. I have my left and right margins set at 10mm which in my mind leaves me with 190mm available for printing.

If I calculate the width of columns A:G in millimetres using;
`Columns("A:G").Width * 25.4 / Application.InchesToPoints(1)`
I am only allowed to go up to around 176.3mm in total.

If I widen any column such that the formula gives 176.5mm or above, column G is not printed.

Why is this so? Is there hidden spacing between columns when printed?